# How do I use frozen Capistrano part 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, rubygems

Following on from [my question on using frozen Capistrano a couple of days back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333072/how-do-i-use-use-frozen-capistrano) I'm still having issues running Capistrano frozen in my vendor folder.

When I try and run my frozen version of cap

```
ruby -r rubygems ./vendor/gems/capistrano-2.5.2/bin/cap deploy-with-migrations
```

I get an error

```
... RubyGem version error: net-ssh(1.0.8 not >= 2.0.0) (Gem::LoadError) ...
```

I have net-ssh-2.0.4 frozen in my vendor folder as I knew it was a dependency so how do I make use of it?

I'd hoped adding my vendor folder to my .gemrc file under the gempath: would have done the trick, but it hasn't. 'gem environment' shows the vendor path, but 'gem list' doesn't show the gems in the vendor folder.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I decided not to freeze Capistrano and dependancies to my vendor gems directory as they weren't gems used by my application - they were used to deploy my application.

Instead I locally installed them on my hosting account and all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely avoid the system-installed gems (which isn't a bad idea if you don't have control over them), I'd install a copy of rubygems to vendor directory.

Set GEM_PATH and GEM_HOME environment variables to /path/to/your/vendor/gems directory, and then install rubygems and go from there.

Comment: By 'install' rubygems there do you just mean freeze it?